# How to skip a column?

Tags: c#, regex

I have textual table:

```
   13.5         0.12557         0.04243         -0.0073         0.00377
     14         0.12573            0.05        -0.00697         0.00437
   14.5         0.12623         0.05823        -0.00703           0.005
     15         0.12853          0.0686        -0.00627         0.00493
   15.5          0.1299         0.08073        -0.00533          0.0063
```

where I would like to match all numbers, except those in first column.
I've tried to use negative lookbehind without success:

```
(?<!^)[\d.E-]+
```

How to match all numbers except those in first column(13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5)?

Comment: Try [`(?:\G(?!^)|^\h*\S+)\h+\K-?\d*\.?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/Ixgj2x/1).

Comment: Or [**`^\s*-?\d[\d.]*\s*\K.+`**](https://regex101.com/r/ye2t8o/1/) if you want to filter out the first column.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: sorry, what is \h and \K? I am trying on RegexBuddy and it doesn't recognize it. However, I'm targeting C#.

Comment: `\h` is for horizontal whitespaces, `\K` lets the engine discard what it has matched thus far.

Comment: @jan, if I set PCRE then \K and \h are recognized, however, not when I set target language to C#...

Comment: You can change @WiktorStribiżew's expression to [**`(?:\G(?!^)|^\s*\S+)(?!\n)\s+(-?\d*\.?\d+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/Ixgj2x/2) then and only use group 1.

Comment: C#? Well, why use regex at all? Split into lines, split each trimmed line with whitespace and omit the first items. At any rate, in C#, a `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]+)(?<=[\p{Zs}\t])\S+")` will do

Comment: See https://ideone.com/oS0FlS

Comment: Or `(?m)(?:^[\p{Zs}\t]*\S+|\G(?!^))[\p{Zs}\t]+(\S+)` can be used, but grab Group 1 value.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: I used `(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]+)(?<=[\p{Zs}\t])[\d\.E-]+`, but it would be great if you could elaborate on it as an answer. Lookarounds are tricky for me...

Comment: Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in case you do not care about data validation, you may do without a regex here:

```
var results = line.Split(new[] {"\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(v => v.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1))
            .SelectMany(x => x);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",results));
// => 0.12557,0.04243,-0.0073,0.00377,0.12573,0.05,-0.00697,0.00437,0.12623,0.05823,-0.00703,0.005,0.12853,0.0686,-0.00627,0.00493,0.1299,0.08073,-0.00533,0.0063
```

In case you want to only match those *numbers* when the data are numbers, you may use

```
    var results2 = Regex.Matches(line, @"(?m)(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]*)(?<=[\p{Zs}\t])-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/pdwIer).

The `-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` float/integer number regex is [explained here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

**Pattern details**

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier that makes `^` match start of the line
- `(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]*)` -  a negative lookbehind that  fails the match if there is a start of the string followed with 0+ horizontal whitespace chars after it imediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<=[\p{Zs}\t])` - a positive lookbehind that requires a horizontal whitespace before a
- `-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` - integer/float number regex:

  - `-?` - an optional `-` char
  - `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
  - `\.?` - an optional `.` char
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of:

    - `[eE]` - a `e` or `E` char
    - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+` char
    - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits.